# Formatting Excel Cells from Access Not Working

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I am trying to simply create an Excel sheet with lots of formatting in it from Access via VBA.

With this example I'm just trying to select A1 to E1 and turn the color of the cells to the color blue with a left border to each cell yet nothing happens, the Excel file opens but it just sits there and does nothing.  What am I missing?

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets(1)

With xlSheet.Range("A1:E1").Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = 5
End With
```

Comment: That makes sense, but even then A1 doesn't have a border.  If I select "C1" without the borders option, it says .ColorIndex isn't a valid property or method, so I don't think this will work at any level.

Comment: A1 does have a border, you just can't see it. Try inserting a column to the left manually to see it, or maybe print preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With xlSheet.Range("A1:E1").Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
```

This only applies a border to the left of `A1`.

Specify each cell:

```
With xlSheet.Range("A1,B1,C1,D1,E1").Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
```

or use a loop:

```
Dim cell As Excel.Range
For Each cell in xlSheet.Range("A1:E1")
   With cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .Weight = xlThin
       .ColorIndex = 5       
   End With
Next
```

Note that `.ColorIndex` is an index into a color palette, not an absolute color. Try the following instead:

```
.Color = vbBlue
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  So it looks like colorindex is not a valid property, I'll need to find another way of changing the color.

Comment: @user18061803 - if you mean changing the color of the cell, try using `.Interior.Color`.

Comment: Yeah I am really just trying to learn how to pass anything I need from Access to Excel.  The VBA does not align like I thought. I am trying to figure out how to select all cells and color them gray as an exercise like what the interior does.  Thanks again.

Comment: I find the macro recorder in Excel quite helpful: record applying the change manually, and then inspect the generated code.

Comment: Got It:
    With xlSheet
        .Range(Cells.Address).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    End With